# SQLite - running on Device

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

FMDB runs great in the simulator, but I get the following errors when I try to run it on the device.

```
"_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet next] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:arguments:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet setupColumnNames] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
```

This question is similar to [sqlite question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188742/iphone-unit-test-with-sql), however, I don't know how to add the fix in xcode or if these are similar problems. How do I fix it so it runs on the device? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by checking and re-adding path to sqlite library.

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib